# How to parallelize this situation with robots

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm working on a robotic problem. The situation is something like this:

1. There are N number of robots (generally N>100) initially all at rest.
2. Each robot attracts all other robots which are with in its radius `r`.
3. I've set of equations with which I can compute acceleration, velocity & hence the position of the robot after time delta`t`. Simply put, I can find the position of each robot after delta`t` time.
4. All I need to do is for a given delta`t`. I need to display position of each robot for every delta`t`.

Problem is actually very simple. Algo will be something like:

```
del_t = ;its given
initialPositions = ;its given
num_robots = ;its given
```

The following code executes for every `del_t`

```
robots = range(1,no_robots)
for R in robots:
    for r in robots:
        if  distanceBetween(r,R) <= radius and r is not R:
            acceleration_along_X[R] += xAcceleration( position(r), position(R) )
            acceleration_along_Y[R] += yAcceleration( position(r), position(R) )
    currVelocity_along_X[R] = prevVelocity_along_X[R] + acceleration_along_X[R] * del_t
    currVelocity_along_Y[R] = prevVelocity_along_Y[R] + acceleration_along_Y[R] * del_t
    curr_X_coordinate[R] = prev_X_coordinate[R] + currVelocity_along_X[R] * del_t
    curr_Y_coordinate[R] = prev_Y_coordinate[R] + currVelocity_along_Y[R] * del_t
    print 'Position of robot ' + str(R) + ' is (' + curr_X_coordinate[R] + ', ' + curr_Y_coordinate[R] +' ) \n'
    prev_X_coordinate[R] = curr_X_coordinate[R]
    prev_Y_coordinate[R] = curr_Y_coordinate[R]
    prevVelocity_along_X[R] = currVelocity_along_X[R]
    prevVelocity_along_Y[R] = currVelocity_along_Y[R]
```

Now I need to parallelize the algorithm and set up the Cartesian grid of MPI processes.

1. Because computation for each robot is an independent task. computation for each Robot 
   *can be* done by an independent thread. Right?
2. I don't know anything about MPI. What does this "Cartesian grid of MPI processes" mean? How can I setup this grid? I've no clue about this.

### EDIT:

Now the problem turned interesting. Actually, it isn't as simple as I thought. After reading [Unode's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875036/how-to-parallelize-this-situation-with-robots/3875227#3875227). I went on to apply his method two by parallelizing using multiprocessing.

This is the code. `printPositionOfRobot` is my serial algo. Basically, it is supposed to print the position of robot (with id *robot_id*) t=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. (Here *del_t* is taken as 1. *num_iterations = 10*. Each of the robot prints message like this: `Robot8 : Position at t = 9 is (21.1051065245, -53.8757356694 )`

There is bug in this code. t=0 locations of bots are given by `position()` for determining xAcceleration & yAcceleration. We need use the positions of previous iterations of all other particles.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import math


def printPositionOfRobot(robot_id):
    radius = 3
    del_t = 1
    num_iterations = 10
    no_robots = 10

    prevVelocity_along_X = 0
    prevVelocity_along_Y = 0
    acceleration_along_X = 0
    acceleration_along_Y = 0
    (prev_X_coordinate,prev_Y_coordinate) = position(robot_id)#!!it should call initialPosition()
    for i in range(1,num_iterations+1):
        for r in range(no_robots):
            if  distanceBetween(r,robot_id) <= radius and r is not robot_id:
                acceleration_along_X += xAcceleration( position(r), position(robot_id) ) #!! Problem !!
                acceleration_along_Y += yAcceleration( position(r), position(robot_id) )#!! Problem !!
        currVelocity_along_X = prevVelocity_along_X + acceleration_along_X * del_t
        currVelocity_along_Y = prevVelocity_along_Y + acceleration_along_Y * del_t
        curr_X_coordinate = prev_X_coordinate + currVelocity_along_X * del_t
        curr_Y_coordinate = prev_Y_coordinate + currVelocity_along_Y * del_t
        print 'Robot' + str(robot_id) + ' : Position at t = '+ str(i*del_t) +' is (' + str(curr_X_coordinate) + ', ' + str(curr_Y_coordinate) +' ) \n'
        prev_X_coordinate = curr_X_coordinate
        prev_Y_coordinate = curr_Y_coordinate
        prevVelocity_along_X = currVelocity_along_X
        prevVelocity_along_Y = currVelocity_along_Y

def xAcceleration((x1,y1),(x2,y2)):
    s = distance((x1,y1),(x2,y2))
    return 12*(x2-x1)*( pow(s,-15) - pow(s,-7) + 0.00548*s )

def yAcceleration((x1,y1),(x2,y2)):
    s = distance((x1,y1),(x2,y2))
    return 12*(y2-y1)*( pow(s,-15) - pow(s,-7) + 0.00548*s )

def distanceBetween(r,robot_id):
    return distance(position(r), position(robot_id))

def distance((x1,y1),(x2,y2)):
    return math.sqrt( (x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2 )

def Position(r): #!!name of this function should be initialPosition
    k = [(-8.750000,6.495191) , (-7.500000,8.660254) , (-10.000000,0.000000) , (-8.750000,2.165064) , (-7.500000,4.330127) , (-6.250000,6.495191) , (-5.000000,8.660254) , (-10.000000,-4.330127) , (-8.750000,-2.165064) , (-7.500000,0.000000) ]
    return k[r]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    no_robots = 10  # Number of robots you need
    p = Pool(no_robots)  # Spawn a pool of processes (one per robot in this case)
    p.map(printPositionOfRobot, range(no_robots))
```

the `position` function in `acceleration_along_X` & `acceleration_along_Y` should return the latest position of the robot.By latest I mean the position at the end of that previous iteration. So, each processes must inform other processes about its latest position. Until the latest position of the bot is know the process must wait.

Other way can be that all processes edit a global location.(I wonder if its possible, because each process have its own Virtual address space). If a process has not yet reached that iteration all other processes must wait.

Any ideas about how to go about it? I guess this is why MPI was suggested in the problem.

Comment: MPI = Message Passing Interface (?) [This document](http://www.davidhastie.me.uk/html/UsingMPI.doc) offered some decent information about MPI and the different methods of setting up parallel systems. (It's a Word doc, though.)

Comment: If you are stuck using MPI to do it, I recently did a class on simple MPI approaches to the N-body problem (which is what you're trying to simulate here, albeit in a different context).   Slides & video are here:  http://www.cita.utoronto.ca/~ljdursi/PSP/Nbody-MPI/Nbody-MPI.html

This is a tricky problem to parallize, becaue every robot requires information from every other robot.  (Real problems simulating these sorts of things use approximations based on the fact that objects further away matter less and less, and so do not need to be treated exactly; but that probably doesn't help you here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the trick here is that at each step, all of the robots have to see the data at some point from all the other robots.    This makes efficient parallelizations hard!

One simple approach is to have each process chuging away on its own robots, calculating the self-interactions first, then getting one by one the data from the other processors and calculating those forces.   Note that this is not the only approach!  Also, real-world solvers for this sort of thing (molecular dynamics, or most astrophsical N-body simulations) take a different tack entirely, treating distant objects only approximately since far away objects don't matter as much as near ones.

Below is a simple python implementation of that approach using two mpi processes (using mpi4py and matplotlib/pylab for plotting).  The generalization of this would be a pipeline; each processor sends its chunk of data to the next neighbour, does the force calcs, and this process repeats until everyone has seen everyone's data.   Ideally you'd update plot as the pipeline progressed, so that no one has to have all of the data in memory at once.

You'd run this program with `mpirun -np 2 ./robots.py` ; note that you need the MPI libraries installed, and then the mpi4py needs to know where to find these libraries.

Note too that I'm being very wasteful in sending *all* of the robot data along to the neighbour; all the neighbour cares about is the positions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy
import pylab
from mpi4py import MPI

class Robot(object):
    def __init__(self, id, x, y, vx, vy, mass):
        self.id = id
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vy
        self.ax = 0.
        self.ay = 0.
        self.mass = mass
    def rPrint(self):
        print "Robot ",self.id," at (",self.x,",",self.y,")"
    def interact(self, robot2):
        dx = (self.x-robot2.x)
        dy = (self.y-robot2.y)
        eps = 0.25
        idist3 = numpy.power(numpy.sqrt(dx*dx +dy*dy + eps*eps),-3)
        numerator = -self.mass*robot2.mass
        self.ax += numerator*dx*idist3
        self.ay += numerator*dy*idist3
        robot2.ax -= numerator*dx*idist3
        robot2.ay -= numerator*dy*idist3
    def updatePos(self, dt):
        self.x += 0.5*self.vx*dt
        self.y += 0.5*self.vy*dt
        self.vx += self.ax*dt
        self.vy += self.ay*dt
        self.x += 0.5*self.vx*dt
        self.y += 0.5*self.vy*dt
        self.ax = 0.
        self.ay = 0.



def init(nRobots):
    myRobotList = []
    vx = 0.
    vy = 0.
    mass = 1.
    for i in range(nRobots):
        randpos = numpy.random.uniform(-3,+3,2)
        rx = randpos[0]
        ry = randpos[1]
        myRobotList.append(Robot(i, rx, ry, vx, vy, mass))
    return myRobotList

def selfForces(robotList):
    nRobots = len(robotList)
    for i in range(nRobots-1): 
       for j in range (i+1, nRobots):
            robotList[i].interact(robotList[j])

def otherRobotForces(myRobotList, otherRobotList):
    for i in myRobotList:
        for j in otherRobotList:
            i.interact(j)

def plotRobots(robotList):
    xl = []
    yl = []
    vxl = []
    vyl = [] 
    for i in robotList:
       xl.append(i.x)
       yl.append(i.y)
       vxl.append(i.vx)
       vyl.append(i.vy)
    pylab.subplot(1,1,1)
    pylab.plot(xl,yl,'o')
    pylab.quiver(xl,yl,vxl,vyl)
    pylab.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    nprocs = comm.Get_size()
    rank   = comm.Get_rank()

    if (nprocs != 2):
        print "Only doing this for 2 for now.."
        sys.exit(-1)
    neigh = (rank + 1) %  nprocs

    robotList = init(50)

    for i in range (10):
        print "[",rank,"] Doing step ", i
        selfForces(robotList)

        request = comm.isend(robotList, dest=neigh, tag=11)
        otherRobotList = comm.recv(source=neigh, tag=11)

        otherRobotForces(robotList,otherRobotList)

        request.Wait()

        for r in robotList:
            r.updatePos(0.05)



    if (rank == 0):
        print "plotting Robots"
        plotRobots(robotList + otherRobotList)
```

Comment: Can you suggest some good resources which explains MPI using python (mpi4py). With python MPI looks simple :)

Comment: mpi4py is definately simpler than doing it in C or FORTRAN... Unfortunately, the mpi4py docs assume an understanding of MPI.   I'd suggest going through a short intro-to-MPI tutorial (there's many out there; one of mine can be found at http://www.cita.utoronto.ca/~ljdursi/PSP/Intro-MPI-PartI/Intro-MPI-PartI.html and http://www.cita.utoronto.ca/~ljdursi/PSP/Homework-IntroMPI-Answers/Homework-IntroMPI-Answers.html).    For mpi4py, a quick summary is that comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD; np=comm.Get_size() and p=comm.Get_rank() gets total number of processors and your process # in that list (from 0..np-1)

Comment: comm.send(<data>, dest=#, tag=#) sends data to process with rank# dest, and an arbitrary tag (but sender + reciever must agree on the tag).  <data>=comm.recv(source=#, tag=#) recieves data from source once its been sent.   send and recv block until completed; to start the send and do something else, do request=comm.isend(..) and then later do a request.Wait() which blocks until its finished.   comm.Allreduce(loc, globsum, op=SUM) globally sums all the loc's into globsum; there's mins & maxes too.  That's enough to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

*Note*: Python's `threads` still run on the same processor. If you want to use the full range of processors of your machine you should use `multiprocessing` (python2.6+).

Using MPI will only bring you clear benefits if the computation is going to be spread over multiple computers.

There are two approaches to your problem. Since you have completely independent processes, you could simply launch the algorithm (passing a unique identifier for each robot) as many times as needed and let the operating system handle the concurrency.

1 - A short Linux shell script (or something equivalent in Windows BATCH language):

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in {0..99}; do
    echo "Running $i"
    python launch.py $i &
done
```

*Note*: the `&` after the launch.py this ensures that you actually launch all processes in consecutive way, rather than waiting for one to finish and then launch the next one.

2 - If instead you want to do it all in python, you can use the following simple parallelization approach:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def your_algorithm(robot_id):
    print(robot_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    robots = 100  # Number of robots you need
    p = Pool(robots)  # Spawn a pool of processes (one per robot in this case)
    p.map(your_algorithm, range(robots))
```

The map function takes care of dispatching one independent operation per robot.

If you do require the use of MPI I suggest [mpi4py](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/).

As for information on what `Cartesian grid` stands for, try [this](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/#Virtual_Topologies)

Comment: `There are two approaches to your problem.` : you mentioned one. And the other is? What does "set up the Cartesian grid of MPI processes." in my problem statement mean? Does it mean "just write this program using MPI". Can you point me to some relevant resources?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't include MPI because your task could be accomplished without using it. Now added.

Comment: I'm following your method2. I don't know why but its not working. Nothing is getting printed. `p = Pool(robots)` is creating the processes. Nothing after that.

Comment: Could you elaborate? It's working fine here. You shouldn't try this on an interactive python session. Save the code as a file and run it with python script_name.py

Comment: Yeah. I did the same. saved it in "temp.py". Just Hit run.  IDLE shows `================= RESTART ==========` next a `>>>` line and the prompt is back. Thats it! nothing else happened. From process explorer I'm able to see that `robots` no. of processes are created. I don't even understand what more info I could give you. BTW I'm using python 2.6.5

Comment: try launching it directly on the terminal (or cmd). I'm not familiar with how IDLE launches the scripts, but it could be interfering with the process.

Comment: Hum I just tried it in Windows and there does seem to be a difference. The print() output is being redirected to somewhere else. however the function does run. Try putting something that writes to a file in the function and check if it works for you. Make sure you use 'a' and not 'w' or you will only see one output.

Comment: Yeah it was IDLE. From terminal it runs fine. Thanks a lot. Now, I need to look into that MPI stuff. Thanks a lot for helping. I'll now start reading about cartesian grid & MPI. I would be more happy if you add any addtional info regarding MPI. Because I have to use it and I'm an absolute noob to it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution too I similar to Unode but I prefer using `apply_async` method in `multiprocessing` as it's asynchronous.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

    def main():
        po = Pool(100) #subprocesses
        po.apply_async(function_to_execute, (function_params,), callback=after_processing)
        po.close() #close all processes
        po.join() #join the output of all processes
        return
```

Comment: I didn't include that option since it didn't seem to be relevant. There was no reference to continuity on the script, the exit state nor running time. And since the size of the Pool is the same as the number of robots, it shouldn't matter.